# Formatting slightly off - count of answers box off edge of background

Tags: bug, design

There has been an apparent CSS change that is infelicitous. When I refreshed some of my stacks, I see the answer-count boxes over the edge of the central area:

[image: CSS is off on this]

This contrasts with the earlier CSS:

[image: CSS is fine on this]